# tooltip value always get the same values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have problem to get different values of tooltip from 3 boxes.
when I click the first box and second box, the value on tooltip won't change..
it always get value from the third box,
so how to get the different value from the box?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ToolTip</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://k-blogger.googlecode.com/files/JQuery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 11px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .activator {
            background: #0099ff;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .tip-item {
            position: relative;
        }

        .tip {
            display: none;
            background: red;
            padding: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 1;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #999;
        }
    </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
     (function($){

       $.fn.BAToolTip = function(options) {  

       //set up default options 
       var defaults = { 
       tipClass: 'tip', //the class name for your tip
       tipFadeEasing: 'easeOutQuint', //easing method
       tipFadeDuration: 200, //fade duration
       tipOpacity: 1, //opacity of tip when mouseover
       tipOffset: 10 //offset the tip relative to mouse cursor in pixels
       }; 

      var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);   

      return this.each(function() {  
      var $this = $(this);

      $this.mousemove(function(e){
      var parentElementOffset = $this.parent().offset();
      var xPos = e.pageX - parentElementOffset.left;
      var yPos = e.pageY - parentElementOffset.top;
      $(this).parent().find('.'+opts.tipClass).css({'top': yPos+opts.tipOffset, 'left' : xPos+opts.tipOffset});
      $(this).parent().find('.'+opts.tipClass).css('display', 'block').stop().animate({opacity:opts.tipOpacity},{duration:opts.tipFadeDuration, easing: opts.tipFadeEasing});
      })

      $this.mouseout(function(){
      $('.'+opts.tipClass).stop().animate({opacity:0},{duration:opts.tipFadeDuration, easing: opts.tipFadeEasing, complete: function(){ $(this).css('display', 'none') } });
        })

      });
    };
  })(jQuery);


    function showValue(a){
        var fom = document.test
        var totalall = eval("fom.totalall"+a);
        var aaa = document.getElementById("total"+a);
        totalall.value = Math.abs(totalall.value.replace(/\./g,"")) + 1;
        aaa.innerHTML = totalall.value;
    }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="test">
        <div class="tip-item">
            <?php for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){ ?>
            <div id="activator<?php echo $i; ?>" class="activator tip-specific-class" onclick="showValue(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
                <div class="tip tip-specific-class">
                    <p id="total<?php echo $i; ?>">0</p>
                    <input type="hidden" name="totalall<?php echo $i; ?>" value=0>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('.activator.tip-specific-class').BAToolTip({
                tipOpacity: 0.9,
                tipOffset: 20
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try and give a minimal working example of your problem. E.g., if this is a frontend problem you are having, there is no need to print out all the php code

Comment: @leo there are 3 boxes, then the boxes can be clicked and show the values of total. the problems are when I click the first box and second box, the value of tooltip won't change, but if I click the third box, the value changes, then if I do hover to the first box and second box, the tooltip value shows the third box tooltip's value.

Comment: I understand that, I just meant that including all the backend stuff in the code in your question makes it much harder to read for anyone trying to help you! If you replace the php code with the actual rendered HTML, think will be a lot clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

willcooler, I feel problem is with your loop. Please replace your form with below form code. I am sure it will fix your issue.

```
<form name="test">

        <?php for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){ ?>
        <div class="tip-item">
        <div id="activator<?php echo $i; ?>" class="activator tip-specific-class" onclick="showValue(<?php echo $i; ?>);">
            <div class="tip tip-specific-class">
                <p id="total<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?> test</p>
                <input type="hidden" name="totalall<?php echo $i; ?>" value=0>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

</form>
```